# How do I access an array in getPixel?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, pixel

Really stuck on this one. So basically, I am trying to retrieve a pixel that I assign in a 2d array in setPixel, but when i try setting pixel=cp[x][y], it's telling me it's null. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

```
public class ColorFrame implements Frame {

    int width;
    int height;
    Pixel pixel;
    int x;
    int y;
    int i;
    int j;
    public ColorPixel cp[][] = new ColorPixel[500][500];
    ColorPixel init_color;

    public ColorFrame(int width, int height, ColorPixel init_color) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.init_color = init_color;
        pixel = pixel;
    }

    public ColorFrame(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        //init_color= new ColorPixel(.5,.5,.5);
        //new ColorFrame(width,height, init_color);
    }

    /*public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }*/
    @Override
    public int getWidth() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return width;
    }

    @Override
    public int getHeight() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return height;
    }

    @Override
    public Pixel getPixel(int x, int y) {
        pixel = cp[x][y];
        return pixel;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPixel(int x, int y, Pixel p) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (i = 0; i <= width; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j <= height; j++) {
                cp[i][j] = init_color;
            }
        }
        cp[width][height] = new ColorPixel(.5, .5, .5);
        //r++;
        //cp[x][y]=getPixel(x,y);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you got `NullPointerEception`.

Put this in you constructor `ColorFrame()`

```
pixel = new Pixel(); // initializing pixel
```

or may be you called `pixel = cp[x][y];` before `setPixel()` function

Answer (score 0):

This code has a whole series of issues (uniitialised members, pixel=pixel in the constructor, member visibility, arrays), but that's not the point.

First, try to put `final` before `ColorPixel init_color` and the IDE will immediately tell you that there is a case when it remains uninitialised: your second constructor leaves it null and so if you use it your whole array will be initialised to null.

If you use the first constructor then you will still get null in `getPixel` as long as `x` or `y` are beyond the original `width` and `height` and below 500 -- you never check the bounds.

If you use the first constructor and your `x` and `y` are within the limits you should get a non-null result (unless you did not pass null for init_color in the constructor).

Comment: Thanks! It's still telling me that every spot in the cp[][] array is null when I try to use it in the getPixel method. I can access the array fine in setPixel. Have any idea why that would be?

Comment: @user3240906 I am sorry, I do not understand your comment: I gave you two reasons why it could be null, since then your code snippet has not changed. Therefore, the same two reasons are still valid, have you tried to address them, and if yes, then how?